# Is there an algebraic proof of MacMahon's result that $\frac1n\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi\left(\frac nd\right)m^d$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory

MacMahon proved that for any integers $m$ and $n\ge0$, $$\frac1n\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi\left(\frac nd\right)m^d$$ is an integer.

I know a combinatorial proof. Does there exist a purely algebraic proof?

The aforementioned  combinatorial proof: let the shift act on $\{1\ldots m\}^n$ and count the number of orbits (see [wikipedia/necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics))).

Comment: Not sure, but a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ has $p(m)$ always an integer for integer $m$ if and only if $$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \binom{x}{k}$$ for integers $a_k.$

Comment: How do you determine the $a_k$'s?

Comment: you have an explicit source for this?  There are references to MacMahon but the topic is partitions...

Comment: @Will Jagy  Applications of a Theory of Permutations in Circular Procession to the Theory of Numbers Get access Arrow
P. A. MacMahon
Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, Volume s1-23, Issue 1, November 1891, Pages 305–318, https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-23.1.305

Comment: Well, for any polynomial we get $a_k$ inductively, $a_0=p(0),$ $a_{k+1}=p(k+1)-\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i\binom{k+1}i.$ But that isn’t very useful here, I think. Just the first thought I had.

Comment: Can you give us an outline of the combinatorial proof? It might help us to get an algebraic proof. My second thought was that $\phi(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)d$ might be useful. Then your sum (ignoring the $\frac1n$) becomes: $$f(n)=\sum_{d_1d_2d_3=n}\mu(d_1)d_2m^{d_3}=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)g(d)$$ where $$g(d)=\sum_{d’\mid d}\frac{d}{d’}m^{d’}.$$ Certainly seems like you want to use arithmetic function rules here, but I don’t see the meaning of $g(d).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, this is a number theory result. We will use some number theory as well as algebra. In particular, that the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ is multiplicative, and a formula for $\phi$ in terms of $\mu.$

Using $$\phi(n)=n\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu(d)}d$$ you get:

$$\frac1n\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(n/d)m^d=\frac1{n}\sum_{d\mid n}m^{d}\frac{n}d\sum_{e\mid \frac nd }\frac{\mu(e)}{e}\\=\sum_{d\mid d’\mid n}\frac{m^d\mu(d’/d)}{d’}\\=\sum_{d’\mid n}\frac{1}{d’}\sum_{d\mid d’}\mu(d’/d)m^{d}$$

Where we substituted $d’=ed.$

We are done if we can prove that $$f(n,m)=\frac1n\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)m^d\tag1$$ is always an integer, or, equivalently, that $$g(n,m)=nf(n,m)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)m^d$$ is always divisible by $n.$

From number theory, we know $f(n,m)$ is an integer when $m$ is a prime power, because $f(n,m)$ counts the degree $n$ monic irreducible polynomials over a field of $m$ elements. But the proof I know for this is a counting proof, and it only works for prime powers $m,$ so I’ll try to prove it more directly.

Let $$X=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \forall m: n\mid g(n,m)\}$$ we want $X=\mathbb N.$

We will show:

1. $1\in X$
2. If $n,n’\in X,$ and $\gcd(n,n’)=1,$ then $nn’\in X.$
3. If $n=p^k,$ with $p$ prime, then $n\in X.$

Altogether, this proves $X=\mathbb N.$

Case $1.$ is trivial.

$2.$ If $n,n’\in X$ and $\gcd(n,n’)=1,$ then:

$$g(nn’,m)=\sum_{d\mid nn’}\mu(nn’/d)m^{d}=\sum_{d_1\mid n’}\mu(n’/d_1)g(n,m^{d_1})$$

is divisible by $n,$ since $g(n,m^{d_1})$ is divisible by $n$ for each $d_1.$. And likewise for $n’.$ So $nn’\mid g(nn’,m)$ for all $m.$ (Here we used that $\mu$ is multiplicative, and the map between the $d\mid nn’$ and pairs $d_1\mid n’,d_2\mid n.$)

So we are only left to prove it for $n$ a prime power.

But when $n=p^k,$ then $$g(n,m)=m^{p^k}-m^{p^{k-1}}=m^{p^{k-1}}\left(m^{\phi(n)}-1\right)$$

If $p\mid m,$ then $n=p^k\mid m^{p^{k-1}},$ and when when $p\not\mid m,$ $m^{\phi(n)}-1$ is divisible by $n.$

So $g(p^k,m)$ is always divisible by $p^k.$

---

In retrospect, you can probably skip that whole first step and just use that $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative, replacing $\mu$ everywhere with $\phi.$

If $$g(n,m)=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(n/d)m^{d}$$ steps $1.$ and $2.$ are essentially the same.

$3.$ is a little harder. When $n=p^k,$

$$g(p^k,m)=m^{p^k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}p^{k-i-1}(p-1)m^{p^i}.$$

And then use cascading congruences using $m^{p^{i+1}}\equiv m^{p^i}\pmod {p^{i+1}}$ recursively on $k.$ You get $g(p^k,m)\equiv pg(p^{k-1},m)\pmod {p^k}.$

---

More generally, if $H$ is a multiplicative function which takes integer values and:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k H(p^{k-i}) m^{p^{i}}$$ is  divisible by $p^k$ for all integers $m,$ then:

$$\sum_{d\mid n} H(n/d) m^d$$ is always divisible by $n.$

A variation of the first step shows that if $H$ has this property, then so does:

$$H_1(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} dH(n/d)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It is impressive.

Comment: I’m curious about the additive group of integer polynomials of degree $\leq n$ of the form $\sum_{d\mid n}a_dx^d$ with values always divisible by $n.$ If $f_n(x)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)x^d,$ then $p_{n,d}(x)=\frac ndf_d(x)$ is such a polynomial, for $d\mid n.$ This shows the group has rank $\tau(n),$ which is the same as the rank of all such polynomials without the divisibility condition. But it is definitely a proper subgroup. Are the $p_{n,d}$ a basis of the group?  If they are a basis for the group, then the quotient group is $\prod_{d\mid n}\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z.$

Comment: For example, for $n=6,$ the prospective basis is $$x^6-x^3-x^2+x,2(x^3-x),3(x^2-x),6x$$ But $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ is always divisible by $6,$ and it isn’t generated by the prospective basis, so it isn’t in general true that these are a basis.

Comment: If $(p,n)=1,$ then $f_{np^a}(x)=f_n(x^{p^a})-f_n(x^{p^{a-1}}).$

Comment: The last can be used to show $f_n(m)$ is always divisible by $n.$ First, $f_1(m)=m$ is always divisible by $1.$ And for any integer polynomial $f(u)-f(v)$ is divisible by $u-v.$ So you just need the step in the proof that shows $x^{p^a}-x^{p^{a-1}}$ is always divisible by $p^a.$